# javafx Bindings.createStringBinding but binding not actually work

Tags: javafx, binding

I'm trying to bind the `textProperty` of the `Label` to the object's `SimpleIntegerProperty` with help of `Bindings` but it does not change the text when I change the  `SimpleIntegerProperty` of the object in real time. Any help would be appreciated of how to make `textProperty` change.

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    private Slider slider;

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        MyObject object = new MyObject(0);

        label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> " hello " + object.numberProperty().get() * (10 + 12)/2));

        object.numberProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty());

    }
}


class MyObject {

    private SimpleIntegerProperty number;

    public Object(int number){
        this.number = new SimpleIntegerProperty(number);
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty numberProperty(){return this.number;}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to "tell" `Bindings`, which `Observable`s to observe for changes. This varargs parameter is the second parameter of the `createStringBinding` method. In this case you need to pass only a single `Observable`: `object.numberProperty()`

```
label.textProperty().bind(
   Bindings.createStringBinding(
      () -> " hello " + object.numberProperty().get() * (10 + 12)/2,
      object.numberProperty()));
```