# JavaFX - Use Binding like a ChangeListener?

Tags: java, javafx, properties, binding

I have an `ObjectProperty` that handles what language my program is currently displaying. When that property changes, every label inside every control needs to update to the correct language.

Right now I do that by doing the following:

```
ObjectProperty<Language> activeLanguage = ...
Label exampleLabel = new Label();
activeLanguage.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> 
{
    exampleLabel.setText(LanguageDatabase.get(LABEL_1));
    // Langdatabase knows what the active language is
    // and returns a string of that label's intended message
    // but translated to the active language
}
```

I make one of these listeners for every single label, button, etc.

How do I do this with `Bindings`?

For example:

```
ObjectProperty<Language> activeLanguage = ...
Label exampleLabel = new Label();

exampleLabel.textProperty().bind(
{
    // How do I say...
    // bind to the language property,
    // but return something completely different
    // ie the LanguageDatabase.get(...)
});
```

Comment: A bit different approach, but if your goal is to minimize the code redundancy, you could create your own class that extends JavaFX Label and in constructor pass in (language property, value of LABEL_1). In constructor you can set the text of the label that you got from LanguageDatabase.get(LABEL_1) and add a listener for language property.

Answer (score -2):

With the help of [fabian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38543352), I located the method to do what I needed. It was a bit hard to spot.

The second parameter is the property that is being watched. That is the key thing I needed.